# Windows XP Mode in Windows 7 Pro comes back with "The requested operation cannot be completed...."

Tags: windows-7, windows

Moderator, please move if another site is more relevant. Thanks.

Windows XP Mode was working fine.  I think I logged off and then I whenever I try to log in I get the following response. "The requested operation cannot be completed because the Terminal Connection is currently busy processing a connect operation"

Through google search, half of the answers are unactionable and half are for Windows Server.

Anybody have specific experience on Windows 7 Pro with Windows XP Mode with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

---

OK, I think I found it. Bob for the win on Win7/XP.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/w7itprovirt/thread/13b052c3-6ef0-4d91-81ac-79c0b70bc7ff

Summary:

1. Enable hidden files to be seen and extensions to be shown for known types.
2. Delete the virtual machine state located at C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Virtual PC\Virtual Machines\Windows XP Mode.vsv
3. Try again.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is one of cases where your scenario isnt applicable, but did you change or remove the password for winxp mode? if that's the case, maybe this can help you out http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/removed-xp-mode-password-in-windows-7-and-now-cant/0f9d0ded-dea5-4b6f-ba75-db0a78a4b3de